# Загрузка контента

Tags: seo, jquery, javascript

Друзья, у меня вопрос. Хочу вот что сделать: после загрузки контента, методом `load`, который берется в `jquery`, загружать остаточный контент.

1. Почему именно после загрузки контента - потому что думаю, поисковый робот не будет анализировать то, что пришло уже потом. Прокатит ли это для СЕО? Хочу загружать по событию `Load` рекламу, баннеры.
2. Если первый пункт прокатит, то скажите, на что вешать `load`? На загрузку тега `html`?

Answer (score 2):

Просто так `ajax`-странички индексироваться не будут, для этого нужно внести кое-какие изменения на сайте, смотрите ниже:

1. [Сканирование AJAX. Руководство для разработчиков и веб-мастеров](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=ru&answer=174992)
2. [Индексация AJAX-сайтов поисковым роботом Яндекса](http://webmaster.ya.ru/replies.xml?item_no=13754)

Comment: Вы не вникли в вопрос - потому ответ не корректный. 
Вы советуете как сделать индексацию страниц ajax'овых роботом, в то время как человеку нужна противоположная задача, что бы весь контент подгруженный динамически **НЕ** индексировался роботом. :)

Comment: @iKuzko - а .load это что по вашему, iframe? ^_^

Comment: true! - исправил :) (убрал замечание про лоад/аякс, но остальное остается в силе)

Comment: Чувствую, что назревает холивар )) Выступаю в поддержку @tranceman. Один из моих проектов основан полностью на ajax и хеш-навигации. Т.е. на какой бы вы странице не находились, то просмотрев исходный (не сгенерированный!) её код, все равно увидите стартовую страницу сайта. Индексируется на "ура" и в гугле, и яндексе. Так что, не опасаясь используйте подгрузку контента ajax-средствами.

Comment: Да уж :) Позвольте мне повториться. Человеку **НЕ нужно** что бы контент подгруженный аяксом **индексировался**. Вы ему советуете как сделать индексацию, а он наоборот хочет ее избежать.  Не вижу в чем может быть холивар.

P.S. я бы тоже дал плюс @tranceman за этот ответ. Индексация аякс сайтов тема полезная, но, к сожалению, это ответ не на данный вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

1. С вероятностью 99% прокатит. Для яндекса работало, для гуглбота тоже. Вероятно, может что-то измениться в ближайшее время, но пока роботы не подгружают контент яваскриптом и не индексируют его.
2. Можете подгружать по событию `ready()` на документ:

   $(document).ready(function(){ ... })